# _ in cookie name causing problems

Tags: php, cookies

I have a web page in which I want to (1) parse a query string, (2) assign values of the parameters to cookies, and (3) redirect the browser depending on accepted languages.  An example URL and the code are below.

In the target page, the values of the cookies named rId and authCode are set, the value of the cookie named GP_UID is always 0.  This is the case in both chrome and firefox.  If I remove the '_' from GP_UID, and use a cookie named GPUID, it works as expected.  According to everything I can find, underscores are acceptable characters for cookie names.  I am confused.

Is there a problem I can't see in my php (perhaps php setcookie disallows underscores in cookie names?) or am I wrong about acceptable cookie names?  Thanks.

```
http://10.0.0.4/~berman/gps-photo.org/index.html?rId=auth&GP_UID=4&authCode=0.895888211205602&license=0


<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
if ( array_key_exists('rId',$_GET) && $_GET['rId'] == 'auth' ){
   setcookie('authCode',$_GET['authCode']);
   setcookie('rId',$_GET['rId']);
   setcookie('GP_UID',$_GET['GP_UID']);
   if ( array_key_exists('license',$_GET) )
     setcookie('license',$_GET['license']);
   else
     setcookie('license',0);
   $pth = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   $ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
   $lng = substr($ua, 0, 2 );
      switch($lng){
      case 'en','es' : break;
      default:
        $lng = 'en';
      break;
   }
   $pth = substr($pth, 0, strrpos($pth,'/')+1);
   $url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$pth.$lng."/index.html";
   // Now redirect to language based subdirectory w. cookies set for auth
   header( 'Location: http://'.$url); //possible replacement for echo above.
   exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: First of all you should use `isset()` instead of `array_key_exists`. Why don't  you clear your cache and cookies and test it again? I've never seen a switch like that. Should be `case 'en'; case 'es'; break;`. Not really seeing why you did it like that anyways. Also, since there a limited amount of cookies, you'll want to reduce yours.

Comment: Why should I prefer isset to array_key_exists?  Also, would be interested in how you would suggest handling different languages?

Comment: `if(isset($GET['rid']))` is less code, therefore faster. Also, `isset()` takes multiple arguments. As far as languages, you're forcing English on any language except Spanish.